# How to check 3 checkboxes upon value in selenium Java

Tags: selenium, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes with **ID** as `id1`,`id2`,`id3` and **name** as `name1`,`name2`,`name3`.

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType_0" type="checkbox"
               name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblType$0" value="Clinician">
        <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType_0">Clinician</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType_1" type="checkbox" 
               name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblType$1" value="Administration">
        <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType_1">Administration</label>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType_2" type="checkbox" 
              name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblType$2" value="Therapist">
       <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType_2">Therapist</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to check it upon the value retrieving from excel.

```
data.getEmpType().get(rowCnt)
```

With above code I will get the value from excel.
How to do it?

Comment: can you specify the full code here with HTML ?

Comment: you mean to say depends on excel values need to check check-box?

Comment: @muraliselenium yes.. i need to check checkbox upon excel value.

Comment: plz provide HTML code of check boxes to help you

Comment: @muraliselenium I have added HTML on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take string value from excel sheet.
Then collect all or required check boxes.
Loop the check boxes and verify against required value which collected from excel.

```
String requiredValue= "from excel file";

List<WebElement> checkBoxes=oWebDriver
    .findElements(By.cssSelector("input[id^='ContentPlaceHolder1'][type='checkbox']"));

for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++) {

    if(checkBoxes.get(i).getAttribute("value").equals(requiredValue)){
        checkBoxes.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}

Or use more straight way through Xpath:

String excelValue = "from excel file";
String xpathExp = String.format(
         "//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_cblType']" + 
         "//td[label[text()='%s']]/input", excelValue );

driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExp)).click();
```

Comment: expecting you check box has input, if it is label then update the css selector

Comment: I need to check more than one checkbox, then wat to do?

Comment: go for one more if condition. The better way is to create whole as method which need to pass string value i.e. which check box to select. call as no of times as required

Comment: thanks, you can accept answer so others came to know it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ExcelValue= "data from excel";

**/*Create a list using common attributes of all three check boxes */**

List< WebElement> CB=driver.findElements(By.xpath("\\input[starts-with(@id,'ContentPlaceHolder1') AND @type='checkbox']"));   

**/*Store size of List created in CB_size(as per your data is should be three */**

int CB_size=CB.size(); 

**/*below loop will execute for all three check boxes one by one and with which so ever your value from excel matches, it click and come out of the loop */**

for (int i = 0; i < CB_size; i++) 

{ 

if(CB.get(i).getAttribute("value").equals(ExcelValue))

{ 

CB.get(i).click(); 

break;

} 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be so kind and fix your indentation, as the code is hard to read